# I want to create json file by substituting values from environment variables in a json template file

Tags: json, powershell, configuration, configuration-files

One requirement of mine is - Using windows, not use any tools not already available as part of aws cli or windows
For example, I have this json file test.json with below content:

`"My number is $myvar"`

I read this into a powershell variable like so:

```
$myobj=(get-content .\test.json | convertfrom-json)

$myvar=1
```

From here, I would like to do something with this `$myobj` which will enable me to get this output:

```
$myobj | tee json_with_values_from_environment.json
My number is 1
```

I got some limited success with iex, but not sure if it can be made to work for this example

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it using the [`Parser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) to find all [`VariableExpressionAst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.variableexpressionast?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) and replace them with the values in your session.

Given the following `test.json`:

```json
{
  "test1": "My number is $myvar",
  "test2": {
    "somevalue": "$env:myothervar",
    "someothervalue": "$anothervar !!"
  }
}
```

We want to find and replace `$myvar`, `$myothervar` and `$anothervar` with their corresponding values defined in the current session, so the code looks like this (note that we do the replacement **before converting the Json string into an object**, this way is much easier):

```bash
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language

$isCore7 = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion -ge '7.2'

# Define the variables here
$myvar = 10
$env:myothervar = 'hello'
$anothervar = 'world'

# Read the Json
$json = Get-Content .\test.json -Raw

# Now parse it
$ast = [Parser]::ParseInput($json, [ref] $null, [ref] $null)
# Find all variables in it,  and enumerate them
$ast.FindAll({ $args[0] -is [VariableExpressionAst] }, $true) |
    Sort-Object { $_.Extent.Text } -Unique | ForEach-Object {
        # now replace the text with the actual value
        if($isCore7) {
            # in PowerShell Core is very easy
            $json = $json.Replace($_.Extent.Text, $_.SafeGetValue($true))
            return
        }
        # in Windows PowerShell not so much
        $varText = $_.Extent.Text
        $varPath = $_.VariablePath

        # find the value of the var (here we use the path)
        $value = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue($varPath.UserPath)
        if($varPath.IsDriveQualified) {
            $value = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.InvokeProvider.Item.Get($varPath.UserPath).Value
        }
        # now replace the text with the actual value
        $json = $json.Replace($varText, $value)
    }

# now we can safely convert the string to an object
$json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

If we were to convert it back to Json to see the result:

```json
{
  "test1": "My number is 10",
  "test2": {
    "somevalue": "hello",
    "someothervalue": "world !!"
  }
}
```

Comment: Kudos to your answer. This code is way beyond my capabilities to adopt and it has a lot of powershell. Is there a easier/lazier way that a newbie can use without compromising on security etc? Even other than powershell?

Comment: @gk_2000 this is the only method I know of, `iex` may work but dont want to deal with that

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.2#executioncontext-expandstring)

```
$myobj = '{test: "My number is $myvar"}' | ConvertFrom-Json
$myvar = 1
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($myobj.test)
```

Output

```
My number is 1
```

Comment: $myobj = '{test: "My number is $myvar"}' is different from
$myobj=(get-content .\test.json -raw)
Please try with the latter to test your solution. It doesn't work.

Comment: $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($myobj) works...!